# How to Implement React-form-builder2 in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

so I want to try react-form-builder2 at next.js but I got a problem when I tried it,

maybe I don't understand English language or indeed the documentation is incomplete, and I just learned to react with next

here is my code, i wrapped my code in my index.

```
 <FormBuilder.ReactFormBuilder
            url={'/'}
            toolbarItems={items}
            saveUrl="/static/json/POST/dummy-post.json"
          />

<FormBuilder.ReactFormGenerator
    form_action="/"
    form_method="POST"
    task_id={12} // Used to submit a hidden variable with the id to the form from the database.
    answer_data={{}} // Answer data, only used if loading a pre-existing form with values.
    //authenticity_token={AUTH_TOKEN} // If using Rails and need an auth token to submit form.
    data={ a={name: 'halo'}} // Question data
  />
```

i have tried to changing that url into my static folder with json extension but, console in next.js refuse it. it said.. 404 not found. and for ReactGenerator i dont know dummy data for answer and authenticity token, etc.

pls.. help me.. i'm stuck